# Woocommerce cURL api to get json in php

Tags: php, api, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to use the Woocommerce REST API to get json data using PHP. How will i get that?

The cURL code is :

```
curl https://example.com/wc-api/v3/products \
-u consumer_key:consumer_secret
```

Node.js returns json but php api isn't? Is there php api to return json data?

[Find documentation for Woocommerce API here](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#view-list-of-products)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting data in the form of PHP Arrays just convert it into JSON:

```
$result = json_encode($returned_array);
```

Comment: Please vote up answers also, It helps us a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, You got to use [WooCommerce REST API PHP Client Library](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library)

Here is an example

```
$products = array();
try {
    $client = new WC_API_Client( store_url, consumer_key, consumer_secret, $options );

    if (isset($_POST['category_id'])) {
        $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
        $products = $client->products->get_categories($category_id);
    }
} catch ( WC_API_Client_Exception $e ) {

    $error_msg = $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    // echo $e->getCode() . PHP_EOL;
}

$response = array();

if ($products) {
    $response['error'] = false;
    $response['data'] = $products;
} else {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = $error_msg;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: can I get custom DB fields in order meta through woocommerce api with php, if yes, please suggest your opinion

Comment: @Gugan yes you can, just check the WooCommerce REST API PHP Client Library for more.

Comment: it returns, meta values of the order but, we have added some additional/custom meta fileds into the wp_postmeta table. Unfortunately, it doesn't return on the meta response too.